# My DEV C++ IDE continously gives me the message:"Id returned 1 exit status" and "Undefined reference to "function(int, int)". How to fix it?

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, exitstatus

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int func(int , int);
main(){
int m[3][3]={(0,0,0),
             (0,0,0),
             (0,0,1)};
int n=3,a;
a=func(m[3][3], n);
if(a==1) printf("True");
else printf ("False");
getch();
}

int func(int m[3][3], int n)
{
int i, j, k=0;
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        if(m[i][j]==1) k=1;

    return k;

}
```

Where am I mistaken? The message of the IDE is :
Funk.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `func(int, int)'
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Funk.cpp but this is actually a C project. May be this the error?
Also, don't use main, but int main(void) or other standard complaint forms

Comment: The function prototype and the function definition are different...

Comment: The initializer for `m` only initializes the first three elements. Change the parentheses to curly braces.

Comment: Yes, I changed the name to Funk.c, and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function prototype and definition of `func` doesn't match. Hence the error. Fix it by changing the function prototype to

```
int func(int[3][3], int);
```

---

The next mistake is that this:

```
a=func(m[3][3], n);
```

should be changed to

```
a=func(m, n);
```

as you want to pass the array, instead of an invalid memory location beyond the array.

---

And I think that you wanted

```
int m[3][3]={{0,0,0},
             {0,0,0},
             {0,0,1}};
```

instead of

```
int m[3][3]={(0,0,0),
             (0,0,0),
             (0,0,1)};
```

---

Also, it is better to use a standard definition of `main`, i.e, change

```
main(){
```

to

```
int main(void) {
```

Comment: Yes, those are the correct parentheses to use, but I noticed they had nothing to do with the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

The linker is expecting a *definition* for `int func(int, int);` but you have not provided that.

You are calling that function in the line `a=func(m[3][3], n);`

The function `func` at the end of your source has the wrong argument types. You're obviously using a C++ compiler (do you mean to do this?) since function *overloading* is not supported in C.